# Allow a sudo sub process to update Zenity running as original user

Tags: bash, pipe, fifo, zenity

1. A script run by user 'staffer' runs [`zenity --progress`](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/3.24/progress.html.en).
2. It then calls `sudo -u adminBod adminScript` (and the STDOUT and STDERR are collected to logger)
3. I want `adminScript` which is running as `adminBod` to be able to write to zenity's STDIN, in order to provide updates.

### Try 1

I thought I could pipe channel 3 to zenity's STDIN then write to that from my sudo process:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Main script, run by 'staffer'
{
  echo "# Starting work"
  exec 3>&1
  sudo -u adminBod adminScript 2>&1 | logger -t myTag
  exec 3>&-
  echo "100" # tells Zenity we're at 100% and it can close
} zenity --progress --auto-close
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# adminScript, run by adminBod
echo "# some message for zenity" >/dev/fd/3
echo "# some message for zenity" >&3
```

This doesn't work because `/dev/fd/3` doesn't exist for `adminBod`.

### Try 2

Then I thought I could use a named pipe, like

```
staffer% mkfifo -m666 thePipe
staffer% zenity --progress --auto-close <thePipe &
staffer% sudo -u adminBod bash
adminBod% echo '# some update'>/home/staffer/thePipe
```

This works in that the message gets received by Zenity, but then it seems to close the channel/pipe (sorry unsure of correct term) so that no further updates can be written.

Comment: For me, your try 2 is working as intended. The pipe is closed (not sure about the terminology either) because echo does only one write and then terminates. You may use cat for testing (or a long-running process): `for i in {0..100} ; do sleep 0.1 && echo $i ; done > pipe`

Comment: try `tail -f thePipe | zenity --progress --auto-close &`

Answer (score 0):

Using `exec 3>thePipe` got me some of the way there...

```
staffer% mkfifo -m666 thePipe
staffer% zenity --progress --auto-close <thePipe &
staffer% sudo -u adminBod bash
adminBod% exec 3>/home/staffer/thePipe
adminBod% echo '# some update' >&3 
adminBod% sleep 1
adminBod% echo '# some new update' >&3
adminBod% sleep 1
adminBod% echo '100' >&3 # will close due to --auto-close
adminBod% exit # this will also close '3' and cause zenity to close
```

But the problem was that when the adminBod session ended, so did the pipe. I wanted zenity to keep running after the sudo-ed sub process ended.

I found that putting an `exec 3>thePipe` in the staffer's process fixed this:

```
staffer% mkfifo -m666 thePipe
staffer% zenity --progress --auto-close <thePipe &
staffer% zenityPid=$!
staffer% exec 3>thePipe #  New line
staffer% sudo -u adminBod bash
adminBod% exec 3>/home/staffer/thePipe
adminBod% echo '# some update' >&3 
adminBod% sleep 1
adminBod% echo '# some new update' >&3
adminBod% exit
staffer% echo '# still running!' >&3
staffer% echo '100' >&3 # will close due to --auto-close
staffer% [[ -e /proc/pid/$zenityPid ]] && kill $zenityPid # kill if not already killed?
```

Also worth note is that as soon as the `exec 3>thePipe` command runs, zenity shows the UI. In my mind, the exec command "opens" the pipe and keeps it open, which is why zenity no longer closess.

However we're supposed to be able to close a numbered pipe with `exec 3>-` but this gives "permission denied". So I don't know if there's a way to close the pipe (like happened in the OP with a simple `echo ... >thePipe`) and/or un-redirect `3`.

So other answers still welcome.

### Edit: the tail -f suggestion from @ljm-dullaart

I could get that working like this:

```
staffer% mkfifo -m666 thePipe
staffer% tail -f thePipe | zenity --progress --auto-close
staffer% echo '# some update' >named
staffer% echo '# some new update' >named # also works :-)
staffer% sudo -u adminBod bash
adminBod% echo '# update from admin' >named
adminBod% exit
staffer% echo '# still working' >named
```

There's an advantage to this method in that you can kill zenity if you store its pid and that then kills tail (broken pipe). Getting `tail`'s pid is a [bit harder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754469/get-the-pid-of-a-command-whose-output-is-piped). Also, I like that it doesn't leave channel/numbered pipe `3` locked into `thePipe`, feels cleaner.